# How to perform the following function using SQL query in c# and SQLSERVER?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

how can i copy all records from one table to another without name repetition and summing their values
in another table. THANKS

```
Source_table
name  value 
a      5
b      10
a      10
```

Desired Output:

```
Dest_table   
name    value  
a        15  
b        10
```

Comment: specify desired output also.

Comment: Does `Dest_table` have any existing records that we need to worry about? Or can we assume it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
INSERT INTO Dest_table
(name,value)
SELECT name,sum(value) AS value
FROM Source_table
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot

Comment: @SaberShabir: please mark it as a answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try following query: but for good post it's better if you format your question properly

```
select name, sum(value) as value from source_table
    group by name
```